# How to do this simple set operation?

Tags: probability, intersection-theory, multisets

> Suppose A and B are events with P(A) 0.4 , P(B)  0.6 and P(A and B) 
>   0.25 . Calculate the probability P(A complement union B).
>
> A 0.25
>
> B 0.65
>
> C 0.75
>
> D 0.85

What I tried?-

P(A union B)=P(A)+p(B)-P(A and B)
i.e=0.4+0.6-0.25=0.75.  I am stuck after this. i know this is simple but I am unable to find the right approach.
[image]

Below is the diagram that I created after solving up to here.

Comment: Start by drawing a little diagram with all the cases (an array with A and not A as lines, B and not B as columns), you'll see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph is fine. Now you can mark the area of $\overline A$. I did this with red lines. It is just the whole rectangle without $A$.

[image]

After that you mark the area of $B$

I did this with blue lines.

[image]

Now the union of this two areas are the whole rectangle without the unmarked area. Because of the values you already have inserted it can be easily seen (calculated) what $P(\overline A \cup B)$ is.

Comment: thanks for such a fine explanation. sorryy I am unable to figure out how to do calculation after this.

Comment: The unmarked area is $0.15$. And the area of the rectangle is $1$. Therefore the marked area is $1-0.15$.

Comment: Thanks it seems. P(A complement) is equal to P(A comp Union B) in this case.

Comment: Not really. $P(\overline A)=1-P(A)=1-0.4=0.6$ and $P(\overline A \cup B)=1-0.15=0.85$ It is comprehensible ? In your exercise the area of $A \cap B$ (blue marked only) is included, which is $0.25$.

Comment: thanks well understood now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice to hear. You´re welcome.